# Why is my Home page not appearing in GitLab project when logged out?

Tags: gitlab, wiki

I have created a GitLab project with a wiki but no code repository. When I visit the project URL, the content of the wiki `Home` page is rendered (where the README is normally rendered).

However, if I log out of GitLab and visit the project URL, the `Home` page is not rendered. Instead a list of recent issue activity appears. I can still visit the wiki while logged out.

How can I make the Home page visible at the project URL to logged-out users?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You cannot make the wiki `Home` page visible to logged-out users who visit the project page. The behavior you have described is as intended and cannot be configured.

Issue [gitlab-org/gitlab-ce#12922](https://gitlab.com/gitlab-org/gitlab-ce/issues/12922) requests support for "wiki-only projects" and is open and unresolved in July 2018. If implemented, it would resolve the issue for your use-case (and require an updated answer here).